# inconsistent mapping in symfony

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine

I have two entities, `User` and `Notification`. In each notification, there is a `sender` and `receiver` that are both `User` entities. But doctrine doesn't like it. The schema validation says:

`The mappings ACME\CoreBundle\Entity\Notifications#sender and ACME\CoreBundle\Entity\User#notifications are inconsistent with each other.`

Here are the mappings for both entities:

```
/**
 * Notifications
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="notifications")
 * 
 */

class Notifications
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="WD\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="notifications")
     */
    protected $sender;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="WD\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="notifications")
     */
    protected $receiver;
}
```

And the User one:

```
/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="My_user")
 * 
 */

class User extends BaseUser
{
   /**
    * @var ArrayCollection
    *
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="WD\CoreBundle\Entity\Notifications", mappedBy="receiver")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
    protected $notifications;
}
```

For readability reasons, I did not put the whole entities code, but I believe these should be enough info.
I believe the error comes from the fact I cannot put two 'mappedBy" values in `User` entity, but I'm not sure. And if it is, then I have no idea how to fix this. 
I've found kinda similar cases on this website, but none that was exactly like mine (or I haven't found them).

Any idea how I could fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue might be that you're having two properties (`sender`, `receiver`) and using the same column to map them. If you need to distinguish between sent and received, you'll need to have `sender` and `receiver` properties on `Notification` and then in your user have `sentNotifications` and `receivedNotifications`. You can combine them in an un-mapped method in your User if you do need to get everything together in one call such as:

```
/**
 * @var Notification[]|ArrayCollection
 */
public function getAllNotifications()
{
    return new ArrayCollection(
        array_merge(
            $this->sentNotifications->toArray(),
            $this->receivedNotifications->toArray()
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: I wanted to try your solution, but after I renamed `notifications` into `sentNotifications`, then added `recievedNotifications` to my `User`entity, I can't update my schema. `doctrine:schema:update` says there is nothing to update. Even after I used `doctrine:generate:entities` I got the same message. I don't get it...? (oh and I also changed /added the mappedBy/invertedBy values, ofc)

Comment: Check your join columns on notifications. Will probably need `@ORM\JoinColumn(name="sender_id", referencedColumnName="id")` and `receiver_id` instead of just `user_id`

Comment: @SKMTH ^ not sure if SO sends inbox notifications if I don't @ you

Comment: You're right, but It still says there's nothing to update. Anyway, the error is gone in the profiler, so I validate the answer. Many thanks to you!